# How to reopen the panel that shows when creating objects?

Tags: interface

When creating objects a panel shows on the left bottom side, like this.

[image]

And sometimes I click other objects or hit Tab going to edit mode then realize I need to tweak some properties on that panel. But it's already gone. Is there any way to bring it back? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this with F9.

But whenever you do something else in between - e.g. move another object - it is gone. Then you cannot call it again.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I can understand this panel no longer accessible if the mesh data has changed. For instance, you moved some vertices of the sphere or you even sculpt it. Then the original properties of that panel such as segments and rings are no longer useful since it's not a serious sphere anymore. I guess that's the reason why the maker makes this way. But selecting between objects or toggle between edit mode and object mode(doing noting) don't really change the mesh data. This panel is still useful for them. Anyway I wish this feature will be improved in the future